# Modifying program using exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception

I need to make a program that initializing class objects throw an exception if the day, month, and year passed as arguments to initialize object variables do not represent a valid date. The exception may only issue an invalid date message.

I do not get much exception in Python, so I did an algorithm that only has an if and else that checks whether it is valid or not. How to transform according to what I need, ie: an exception if the day, month, and year passed as arguments to initialize object variables do not represent a valid date?

```
def dois(day, month, year):
    checks = "true"
    i = 0
    while checks == "true" and i == 0:
        if (year%4 == 0 and year%100!= 0) or year%400 == 0:
            leap_year = "sim"
        else:
            leap_year = "nao"

        if month < 1 or month > 12:
            checks = "false"

        if day > 31 or ((month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11) and day > 30):
            checks = "false"

        if (month == 2 and leap_year == "nao" and day > 28) or ( month == 2 and leap_year == "sim" and day > 29):
            checks = "false"
        i = i + 1

    if checks == "true":
        print("Valid date")
    else:
        print("Invalid date")
```

I can not use ready-made functions like time.strptime, I need to use what I have implemented

Comment: How academic does this need to be…? In practice you'd do `datetime.datetime(year, month, day)` and let *it* raise an exception.

Comment: Why the `while`?! It's only ever doing one iteration of that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer:

```
import datetime

try:
    datetime.date(year, month, day)
    print('Valid date')
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Invalid date')
```

The `try..except..raise` is really just to satisfy the condition that *"the exception may only issue an invalid date message"* (whatever that means exactly). In practice you would just use the `ValueError` raised by `date` as is. I don't know what the point if this exercise is, whether converting an exception or reinventing date parsing is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
# declare a new exception class
class ValidationException(Exception):
    pass

# later
if checks != "true":
    raise ValidationException("Invalid data")
```